# Fit text within a container by reducing font-size and truncating text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have to fit text within a div container which is square. If the text is too large to fit within the container, I have to reduce the font-size from 32px to 18px. And even if that is not fitting, I have to truncate the text with "...". It looks simple enough. I am using plain JavaScript / React.

There are some approaches that I am trying.

```
<div className="container" ref={c => { this.comp = c; }}>
  {text}
</div>
```

If the clientHeight < scrollHeight, the text overflows, hence I reduce the font size.

```
if (this.comp.clientWidth < this.comp.scrollHeight) {
  this.setState({ overflow: true });
}
```

I am setting a style on the container based on the state changes.

```
style={this.state.overflow ? { fontSize: 18 } : undefined}
```

I like to reduce to truncate the text if it still overflows. Not sure how to truncate the text.

Code snippet so far:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.comp.clientHeight < this.comp.scrollHeight) {
      console.log('reducing font size from 32px to 18px');
      this.setState({ overflow: true });
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    const { overflow } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container" 
           ref={c => { this.comp = c; }} 
           style={overflow ? { fontSize: 18 } : undefined}
      >
        This is a long text which wont fit within the container. Inspite of reducing the font size, it wont fit. And I want to truncate with ellipsis. It is not possible with text-overflow as it is multi-line text. How do I figure how many characters to truncate it to?
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: And what are you doing with `state.fontSize`?

Comment: @Pete that works only for single line text! No white space wrap.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/

Comment: @Pete Added a minimal example. But I have no clue how to find the number of characters to truncate it to.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by updating the component text till it fits. And then finally setting the state. The code snippet is shown below.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let overflow;
    if (this.comp.clientHeight < this.comp.scrollHeight) {
      overflow = true;
      this.comp.style.fontSize = '18px';
    }
    let truncatedText;
    while (this.comp.clientHeight < this.comp.scrollHeight) {
      const words = this.comp.innerText.split(' ');
      words.pop();
      truncatedText = words.join(' ') + '...';
      this.comp.innerText = truncatedText;
    }
    this.setState({
      overflow,
      truncatedText
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      overflow,
      truncatedText
    } = this.state;
    const text = 'This is a long text which wont fit within the container.Inspite of reducing the font size, it wont fit.And I want to truncate with ellipsis.It is not possible with textoverflow as it is multiline text.How do I figure how many characters to truncate it to.';
    
    return ( <div className = "container"
      ref = {
        c => {
          this.comp = c;
        }
      }
      style = {
        overflow ? {
          fontSize: 18
        } : undefined
      }>
      {truncatedText || text} 
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Keep reducing the text till it fits and finally update the state.

```
    let truncatedText;
    while (this.comp.clientHeight < this.comp.scrollHeight) {
      const words = this.comp.innerText.split(' ');
      words.pop();
      truncatedText = words.join(' ') + '...';
      this.comp.innerText = truncatedText;
    }
```